# How do I get HTTPs w/ Express working with websockets on the same port using node?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have the following code that works...

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    ...
})
```

This works great so I try to convert to https...

```
const app = express();
const server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.KEY_FILE),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_FILE)
}, app);
server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    ...
})
```

I can now connect via my express routes but not my websocket. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Oops using https makes it secure ws so you need to use the `wss://` address instead of `ws://`